# Let $A$ be $C ^ {*}$ algebra, $a ∈ A$,$ p$, $q ∈ A$ be orthogonal projections Show that if a is positive and $pap = 0$, then $paq = 0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be $C ^{ *}$ algebra, $a ∈ A$, $p$, $q ∈ A$ be orthogonal projections. Show that if a is positive and $pap = 0$, then $paq = 0$.

from orthogonal projection condition we have that $pq=0$ but how can this be used/related to solve the problem?

Comment: Exactly how does $pq=0$ follow? I doubt it...

Comment: if $a$ is positive and $p$ is self-adjoint (which a projection is), then $a=b^*b$ for some $b \in A$ and $pap = (bp)^*(bp) = 0$....

Comment: Do you even need them to be orthogonal? Doesn't seem so to me. Give me a moment to sanity check this.

Answer (score 2):

Since $a\geq 0$, then $a = b^*b$ for some element $b$ inside $A$. This allows us to write (by the $C^\ast$-identity)
$$
0 = \Vert pap \Vert = \Vert (bp)^*bp \Vert= \Vert bp \Vert^2
$$
and thereby $bp=0$. Applying the adjoint yields $pb^*=0$. Hence $ paq = (pb^*)bq = 0$, and we're done.